# Windows are slightly "transparent" in such a way I can see underlying windows show through slightly to the current window

Tags: mac, macos

I don't know how to explain it too well. Here are some places I see this happen:
On the Minecraft main menu, I can see through to the desktop,
While watching a youtube video (in full screen) I can see remnants of the previous page,
etc.

How the heck do I fix this? It is really bugging me.

EDIT: It appears to be because of the hardware, since this also happens under Ubuntu.

Comment: If you create a new user account, do you get the weird behavior there?

Comment: @samh yes. I have also noticed I get this under Ubuntu.

Comment: looks like persistent image (https://www.engadget.com/2013/02/18/the-curious-case-of-the-persistent-image/)

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the "features" of the Mac O/S that I always thought, "what were they thinking?" Unfortunately I don't have an answer to that but to your question:

Go to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display

look for two check boxes: Increase Contrast and Reduce Transparency.

Adjust either or both to get your desired effect, that is not seeing the stuff behind a window.

Comment: If he's seeing artifacts while watching full screen video, theres something wrong. That's not a feature.

Comment: Hmmmm... I took this to mean the artifacts you get when transparency was turned on. But yeah if that is happening more is wrong than just a setting.